# compare current system date&time with date that is stored in data&time base in android

Tags: android, database, date, time

how to compare current system time with time that is stored in data base in android?
i use this code:

```
 public static long s ;
.
.
.
.

Time now = new Time();
 now.setToNow();
String query = "SELECT Cart_ID,Cart_Date from Tbl_Cart where Cart_ID="+lastId+" ";
         // String queryt = "SELECT Cart_Date from Tbl_Cart where Cart_ID="+lastId+" ";
          Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
           if (c != null && c.moveToFirst() ) {
               s = c.getLong(0);


           }

          if(s==now.setToNow())
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If yours stored time is in millisecond then you can compare with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.
Also you can think carefully about comparing with '==' .Because long time changes so rapidly, its very difficult to getting match with System time.You can better look for less/greater or equal with some time frame.

Answer (score 0):

This code is only for data you can do same for time also.
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

```
    CalCurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            // that will pass cureent date .
    Current_Date = dateFormat.format(CalCurrentDate.getTime());
```

**Fetch Date & Time From DB Using SQL Query :**

Current_Date : Current data and compare by this Query.

```
selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE `Date`>='"+Current_Date+"'";
```

Now you can run this Query as **rawQuery()**.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on how you store the data-time in your database.

If you store like date-time then you can take the individual object in to the calender and then compare it with the System.currentTimeMillis();

e.g:

```
  Calendar start_time = new GregorianCalendar();
  start_time.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, sHour);
  start_time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, sMinute);
```

then compare it with systemtime like

**If(start_time.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis())**

OR

If you store the date-time in the times in Millis formate then you can directly compare it.

e.g:

**if(yourTimes <= System.currentTimeMillis())**

Hope it will help you.

Comment: will System.currentTimeMillis()  use for date too?

Comment: yes. But Please see that you are also using the date in calender if you are going to compare it with the date.

Comment: i stored date automatically in database(current system date-type date time),and i don t need calender,i do this:  String query = "SELECT Cart_Status,Cart_ID,Cart_Date from Tbl_Cart where Cart_ID="+lastId+" ";    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);    s2=c.getLong(1);       System.currentTimeMillis()!=s2)